# Text too large in Gmail app (Android) in Mailchimp newsletter

Tags: css, media-queries, mailchimp, newsletter

I've ran an inbox inspection and my newsletter looks great on all devices except Gmail.

Gmail decides to render my email as it would on desktop and in doing that a lot of the text overlaps each over and is generally too large.

I've read that Gmail ignores media queries which is unfortunate and I've read that I must inline my CSS for it too work. But then that would ruin every other view except Gmail.

Is there a solution to this or should I just hope people click "view this email in a browser"

Comment: Well 18px is the size of the text, which is too big in gmail.

If i then change it to 12px it looks fine in the Gmail Android app. but then if somebody is viewing on desktop it looks too small

Comment: I've already said that Gmail ignores media queries, that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

First off, Never rely on people clicking to view the web version of your email. 
And **ALWAYS** inline your styles. Except media queries which cannot be inlined.

Yeah we have to inline for Gmail but it's worth it. 
Now, obviously I don't know the figures for your email client market share but I would definitely make your email work in Gmail.

But as you have pointed out, it will either appear too big or too small depending on the device being used. 
Is there no middle ground that you could get away with, that is close to what you would want on any screen size?

Comment: You're right, people aren't obliged to view my email so if it isn't easily readable they'll ignore it.
I coded my own template in Mailchimp so I could put 4 products in each row so maybe that's where I'm going wrong, maybe I should stick to three products per row then there wouldn't be as much text.
I did manage to solve this problem (sort of) by giving the product blocks a set width rather than a percentage, this forced gmail to display 1 product on each row which is what I wanted on mobile view except they are all off-centre to the left.

Comment: Hmm yeah it's a tough one, no matter what you do with Gmail. 
Here is a new technique that makes your emails responsive in Gmail, meaning you could pick one font size for all screens. That could help instead of picking a larger font for the sake of mobile: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-future-proof-responsive-email-without-media-queries--cms-23919

Comment: And I have tested the above technique in Email on Acid and it works flawlessly as far as I'm concerned.